# Writing rules for rspamd to filter by email name and fuzzy score

Tags: lua, rspamd

The situation is as follows. There is whitelisted domain(ours) and we receive letter with the same addresses as ours but with phishing content. Since it's whitelisted it gets the low spam score. Fuzzy gives the high score but it's not enough to push it as spam.

In the multimap.conf i have white scores like this:

```
sender_from_whitelist_user {
    #type = "selector";
    type = "from";
    filter = "email";
    score = -10.0;
    #selector = "from({'smtp', 'orig'})";
    map = ["/var/lib/rspamd/whitelist_from_ldap.map.inc","/var/lib/rspamd/whitelist_manual.map.inc"];
    symbol = "SENDER_FROM_WHITELIST_USER";
    prefilter = true;
    action = "accept"; # Prefilter mode
    group = "local";
    is_whitelist = true;
}

sender_from_whitelist_domain {
    type = "from";
    filter = "email:domain";
    score = -5.0;
    map = "/var/lib/rspamd/whitelist_from_domains.map.inc";
    symbol = "SENDER_FROM_WHITELIST_DOMAIN";
    prefilter = true;
    action = "accept"; # Prefilter mode
    group = "local";
    is_whitelist = true;
}
```

Is it possible to wright a rule that will say
IF email:domain = ourdomain.com AND fuzzy_score >= 9 THEN reject(or move to spam folder)

How can i do it?